# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context - swift 3

Tags: realm, swift3

I have a following line of code which initializes Realm object:

```
lazy var realm = try! Realm(configuration:Realm.Configuration(deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true))
```

It was working perfectly in swift 2 but in swift 3, its giving following error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

The [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realm-configuration) also doesn't suggest any change.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue with Swift's type checker, but you can work around it for now by explicitly specifying the type:

```
lazy var realm: Realm = try! Realm(configuration:Realm.Configuration(deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true))
```